# Issue with UPDATING Database after deletion of someting !

Tags: c#, data-binding

I'm working on basic sql, using C# with binding options and adapters.  I have sucessfully added data to my database and can then update with no problems. But when I try to delete some data and then UPDATE it throws an exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>   Additional information: Update requires a valid DeleteCommand when passed DataRow collection with deleted rows.

The code:

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    table1TableAdapter.Update(dataSet1);
}

private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    table1BindingSource.RemoveCurrent();
}
```

Why can't I update my database after removing something from it?

Answer (score 0):

You're remove code isn't deleting anything from the db.  It's removing the *binding* to the datasource.  So when you call `Update()` on that datasource it's no longer bound to anything.

Comment: Call your Adapter's Delete function rather than your DataSource's RemoveCurrent()

Comment: Adapter Dont have any Delete or Remove Function :O